# a href tags on the outside of div tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml, tags

I understand that div tags are containers for most tags, such as a href tags... with that said I have a document that works and only functions when the a href tag is around two div tags.

If I adjust the div and a href so that it is w3c compliant, it distorts the website. I could possibly adjust my .js and .css to make it work, but I would like to find an alternate solution. Can I keep the a href tag where it is now?

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Link Here: http://momentum.freeiz.com/

Code Here:

```
<a href="hapo.htm" >        
  <div class="boxgrid_slideright">
    <div id="slideshow">
      <img class= "cover" src="images/home/ hapo/0.jpg" width="161" height="107" alt="hapo credit union"/>
      <img class= "cover" src="images/home/ hapo/1.jpg" width="161" height="107" alt="hapo credit union"/>
      <img class= "cover" src="images/home/ hapo/2.jpg" width="161" height="107" alt="hapo credit union"/>
      <img class= "cover" src="images/home/ hapo/3.jpg" width="161" height="107" alt="hapo credit union"/>
      <img class= "cover" src="images/home/ hapo/4.jpg" width="161" height="107" alt="hapo credit union"/>
    </div><!--slideshow--> 
  </div><!--boxgrid-->
</a>
```

Comment: I guess my code didn't show up, here is the link: http://momentum.freeiz.com/

Comment: You really shouldn't put block elements inside `<a>` elements, because some browsers (Safari) can behave weirdly. Instead, you can put any number of inline-type elements (span, etc), and blockify with css: `display: block; float: left/right; etc`

Comment: If you change the `div` elements to `span` elements, then you'll be nesting inline elements, which is allowed.

Comment: nice, thanks for the quick responses:)

Comment: Alternatively, if the block behaviour is necessary, an onClick might be the way to go.

Comment: @biziclop block elements inside `<a>` elements are perfect valid in HTML5: [The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links).](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-a-element.html#the-a-element)

Comment: Tons of great info... thanks everyone. I tried both onclick and span onlick worked well, but w3c validator still showed an error. how are span tags represented in css, e.g. div class "example" = .example and div id "example" = #example

Comment: @steveax, there are no other buttons or links, but there are div tags that reference javascript functions, is this not acceptable?

Comment: Are you selecting the HTML5 option as the doctype in the validator?

Comment: my site is set to doctpye, xhtml...

Comment: Well, that would be the issue. Block elements are only allowed inside `a` elements in HTML5. There's really no good reason to use any other doctype these days.

Comment: This was my first website, that wasn't flash/as3, so I was watching tutorials and the person I was following chose that doctype. Is it to late to change?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

Comment: nm, got it, but the list of errors just went up, lol.. fml

Answer (score 3):

You should style inline elements to behave as block element with css:

CSS:

```
a.whatever, .boxgrid_slideright, .slideshow {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="whatever" href="hapo.htm" >        
  <span class="boxgrid_slideright">
    <span id="slideshow">
      <img class= "cover" src="images/home/ hapo/0.jpg" width="161" height="107" alt="hapo credit union"/>
      <img class= "cover" src="images/home/ hapo/1.jpg" width="161" height="107" alt="hapo credit union"/>
      <img class= "cover" src="images/home/ hapo/2.jpg" width="161" height="107" alt="hapo credit union"/>
      <img class= "cover" src="images/home/ hapo/3.jpg" width="161" height="107" alt="hapo credit union"/>
      <img class= "cover" src="images/home/ hapo/4.jpg" width="161" height="107" alt="hapo credit union"/>
    </span><!--slideshow--> 
  </span><!--boxgrid-->
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

XHTML 2 was going to allow use of the “href” attribute on any element, allowing for block level anchors and eliminating repetition of the same anchor in some cases or unnecessary additional tags in others. This really made sense, since the “a” tag is just a span, but the only span with an added ability of linking to somewhere else. There is really no special semantic meaning to the “a”, and all links on a page could be found in parsing by finding tags with the “href”. In the early days of the development of HTML 5, the “href anywhere” approach was discussed, and I was excited thinking it was going to be part of HTML 5. At the time, that was the most interesting thing about HTML 5 to me. But “href anywhere” would mean all previous browsers would not be able to see links at all (besides for the ones put in “a” tags for some reason), so the idea was scrapped. Instead, the HTML 5 creators took advantage of an against-spec ability that current browsers already had: block level anchors. Browsers at least back to IE 6 will happily make “flow content” placed in an “a” tag into a link. [via](http://tobymackenzie.wordpress.com/2010/09/13/html5-href-anywhere-attempt/) - Toby Mackenzie

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links

http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/